# Cannot find type 'GADInterstitial' in scope?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

I just upgraded Google Mobile Ads SDK to version 8.0, but I am getting this error:

> Cannot find type 'GADInterstitial' in scope

I also added this code to AppDelegate:

```
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
```

Google Mobile Ads SDK worked perfectly until I upgraded to version 8.0

Note: I also use Firebase Framework in my app.

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/migration?hl=en#class_renames , GADInterstitial has been renamed to GADInterstitialAd

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here this is the code of Admob Interstitial only copy and paste
I just upgraded Google Mobile Ads SDK to version 8.0

```
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController,GADFullScreenContentDelegate{
    
private var interstitial: GADInterstitialAd?
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let request = GADRequest()
        GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID:"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910",request: request,
        completionHandler: { [self] ad, error in
          if let error = error {
             return
             }
             interstitial = ad
             interstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
            }
        )
}

 func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
   print("Ad did fail to present full screen content.")
 }

 func adDidPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
   print("Ad did present full screen content.")
 }

 func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
   print("Ad did dismiss full screen content.")
 }   

@IBAction func AddAction(_ sender: UIButton) {        
    if interstitial != nil {
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
      } else {
        print("Ad wasn't ready")
      }
}
```

}

Answer (score 13):

Google Mobile Ads SDK 8.0 has a dramatic change of its API interfaces. Please refer to Google's [official document for Interstitial](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial). To make it complete, here is the reference to the [legacy API](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial-v7) prior to 8.0.

The main changes are the delegate and the Ad class:

| old | new |
| --- | --- |
| GADInterstitialDelegate | GADFullScreenContentDelegate |
| GADInterstitial | GADInterstitialAd |

And instead of initializing the Ad in the legacy way:

```
interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
let request = GADRequest()
interstitial.load(request)
```

it's now initialized in the following way

```
let request = GADRequest()
GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID:"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910",
                            request: request,
                  completionHandler: { [self] ad, error in
                    if let error = error {
                      print("Failed to load interstitial ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                      return
                    }
                    interstitial = ad
                    interstitial?.delegate = self
                  }
```

And the new GADFullScreenContentDelegate methods:

```
/// Tells the delegate that the ad failed to present full screen content.
func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
  print("Ad did fail to present full screen content.")
}

/// Tells the delegate that the ad presented full screen content.
func adDidPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
  print("Ad did present full screen content.")
}

/// Tells the delegate that the ad dismissed full screen content.
func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
  print("Ad did dismiss full screen content.")
}
```

Note there is no longer the `interstitialDidReceiveAd` method. Instead you either start to present the Ad in the `GADInterstitialAd.load()` completion call back, or at a later stage to present the Ad if it is initialized:

```
if interstitial != nil {
  interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
} else {
  print("Ad wasn't ready")
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Google have updated the SDK without telling anyone.
Take a look at the new guide on Admob for adding an interstitial.
Essentially GADInterstitial has changed to GADInterterstitialAd and you have to use a different Delegate too.

Thanks for that Google.

Comment: Google is notorious for making changes without telling anyone or even explaining or giving anyone a heads up.  They are worse than Apple on that front.